# append multiple results from one list to another

Tags: python, list, append

```
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter, methodcaller
from itertools import chain

list1 = []
list2 = []

oso = openStationOrder()
pi = prodInfo()
for result in oso:
    result1 = result.split(',')
    list1.append(result1)
    result2 = sorted(list1, key = itemgetter(4))

for aaa in result2:
print aaa
```

result:

```
['aaa664847', ' Completed', ' location' , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
['aaa665487', ' Completed', ' location' , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
['aaa661965', ' Completed', ' location' , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
['aaa669696', ' Completed', ' location' , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
['aaa665376', ' Completed', ' location' , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
['aaa661966', ' Completed', ' location, , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
['aaa664855', ' Completed', ' location, , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
['aaa665488', ' Completed', ' location, , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
['aaa664510', ' Completed', ' location, , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
```

i then index: #first list

```
for res in result2:
    res1 = res[0]
    list1.append(res1)
```

result:

```
['aaa664847', 'aaa665487', 'aaa661965'...]
```

second list:

```
for k in pi:
    k1 = k.split(' ')[0]
    list2.append(k1)

print k
```

result:

```
aaa664288 Image  1,
aaa664847 Image  6,
aaa664847 Video  12

    print list2

[aaa664288, aaa664847, aaa664847]
```

then I use intersection to find the the matching 'aaa123456' numbers in the two list

```
match = set(list1).intersection(list2)

for m in match:
    print m
```

result: # it states that the only matching aaa number is aaa664847

```
aaa664847
```

i would like the outcome to be:

```
['aaa664847', ' Completed', ' location' , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000', Image 6, Video 12]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: the poster now says in a comment "he needs the k appended" and he means back when he computed:

```
for k in pi:
    k1 = k.split(' ')[0]
    list2.append(k1)
```

This of course requires "the k" to be preserved and a `dict` looks right for that.  So let's change this loop to:

```
theks = {}
for k in pi:
    pieces = k.split(' ')
    theks[k[0]] = k[1:]
```

`list2` is not needed any more, we'll just use `theks` -- so below I'll comment out uses of `list2` and substitute `theks`:

```
list1  = [
  ['aaa664847', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000'],
  ['aaa665487', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000'],
  ['aaa661965', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000'],
  ['aaa669696', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000'],
  ['aaa665376', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000'],
  ['aaa661966', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000'],
  ['aaa664855', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000'],
  ['aaa665488', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000'],
  ['aaa664510', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
]

for row in list1:
    if row[0] in theks:
        print(row + theks[row[0]])
```

Checking membership in `dict` `theks` is just as fast as it was to check membership in a `set` in my previous version.

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  However, i need the information from the 'k' print out (image6, video12) appended to the original list(list1) if the 'aaa123456' numbers matched from list1 and list2.  everything works great until i get to that point. 
['aaa664847', ' Completed', ' location' , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000', Image 6, Video 12]

Comment: @Shane_McC, you haven't preserved that `k`.  A dict would be fine.  Let me edit my A to show you how.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with the code and the way results are shown in your question, but after quite a bit — way too much — time spend just deciphering your question, I think the following does what you want if I've manged to understand it:

```
from operator import itemgetter

oso = [
  'aaa669696, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000',
  'aaa664847, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000',
  'aaa661965, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000',
  'aaa665376, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000',
  'aaa665487, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000',
  'aaa664510, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000',
  'aaa664855, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000',
  'aaa665488, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000',
  'aaa661966, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000',
]

list1 = []
for result in oso:
    result1 = result.split(',')
    list1.append(result1)

result2 = sorted(list1, key=itemgetter(4))
print 'result2:'
for aaa in result2:
    print ' ', aaa
print
```

```
result2:
  ['aaa669696', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
  ['aaa664847', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
  ['aaa661965', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
  ['aaa665376', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
  ['aaa665487', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
  ['aaa664510', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
  ['aaa664855', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
  ['aaa665488', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
  ['aaa661966', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']
```

```
list1 = []
for res in result2:
    res1 = res[0]
    list1.append(res1)

print 'list1:', list1
print
```

```
list1: ['aaa669696', 'aaa664847', 'aaa661965', 'aaa665376', 'aaa665487', 
        'aaa664510', 'aaa664855', 'aaa665488', 'aaa661966']
```

```
pi = [
  'aaa664288 Image  1',
  'aaa664847 Image  6',
  'aaa664847 Video  12',
]

print 'pi:'
list2 = []
for k in pi:
    k1 = k.split(' ')[0]
    list2.append(k1)
    print ' ', k

print
print 'list2:', list2
```

```
pi:
  aaa664288 Image  1
  aaa664847 Image  6
  aaa664847 Video  12

list2: ['aaa664288', 'aaa664847', 'aaa664847']
```

```
matches = set(list1).intersection(list2)
print 'matches:', matches
print
```

```
matches: set(['aaa664847'])
```

```
print 'results:'
for m in sorted(matches):
    for row in result2:
        if row[0] == m:
            result = row[:]  # make separate copy
            for k in pi:
                k1 = k.partition(' ')
                if k1[0] == m:
                    result.append(k1[2])
            print ' ', result
```

```
results:
  ['aaa664847', ' Completed', ' location', ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000', 
   'Image  6', 'Video  12']
```

Comment: BTW, you can get rid of the excess whitespace around items by using `result1 = [s.strip() for s in result.split(',')]` instead of `result1 = result.split(',')`when creating `list1` in the `for` loop near the beginning.

Comment: what would be the best course of action if I wanted to take the 'results' (with the appended image and video) and update 'result2', removing the original?

Comment: Hmm, sounds like you could be using my answer, not the one you accepted (in which case you should change your selection). Anyway, to answer your follow-on question, you could do it simply by changing the `result = row[:]  # make separate copy` to `result = row  # row to be updated`.

Comment: Honestly, I am using all three versions and trying to learn how each one works. If i may add one more question. If i took your printed 'result2'(lets say they were sorted by time) how could i take the 2 most recent? I have tried putting result2 back into another list and taking [-2:]

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = [','.join(items) for items in [    
    ['aaa664847', ' Completed', ' location' , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000'],
    ['aaa665487', ' Completed', ' location' , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000'],
    ['aaa661965', ' Completed', ' location' , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000'],
    ['aaa669696', ' Completed', ' location' , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000'],
    ['aaa665376', ' Completed', ' location' , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000'],
    ['aaa661966', ' Completed', ' location' , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000'],
    ['aaa664855', ' Completed', ' location' , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000'],
    ['aaa665488', ' Completed', ' location' , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000'],
    ['aaa664510', ' Completed', ' location' , ' mode', ' 2014-xx-ddT00:00:00.000']]]

d2 = '''aaa664288 Image  1,
aaa664847 Image  6,
aaa664847 Video  12'''.splitlines()
```

use dict

```
from __future__ import print_function  # for python3 style
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter, methodcaller
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

data1 = {}
data2 = defaultdict(list)

oso = d1  #openStationOrder()
pi = d2  #prodInfo()
for result in oso:
    result1 = result.split(',')
    data1[result1[0]] = result1

result2 = sorted(data1.values(), key=itemgetter(4))
for aaa in result2:
    print(aaa)

#for res in result2:
#    res1 = res[0]
#    list1.append(res1)
list1 = list(data1.keys())
print(list1)

for k in pi:
    k = k.split(' ', 1)
    print(k)
    data2[k[0]].append(k[1])
list2 = list(data2.keys())
print(list2)

match = set(list1).intersection(list2)
for m in match:
    print(data1[m] + data2[m])
```